# Avoiding curl output of " % Total % Received % Xferd Average" in logfile of Raspberry Pi

Tags: logging, debian, raspbian

I am starting a python script at boot time via /etc/rc.local with myScript.py &

This script triggers a web-interface using curl. Everything runs well but I am getting all these

"rc.local[387]:   % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current"

entries in my /var/log/daemon.log

Is there an way to suppress those messages but not e.g. error messages from within the script?

Comment: you shouldn't use `rc.local` in the first place.checkout systemd-units or simiilar. and since this question is not about programming, you probably should ask on [su] or on [Raspberry Pi](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/) instead...

Comment: Use `curl -s -S ...`.  `-s` silences everything, `-S` allows error reports when `-s` is in force.

Comment: thanks! I tried the -s solution but this also removes the intended output I was not referring to earlier. I now simply use the myScript > /dev/null & as a work around.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If using curl version 7.67.0+ (from November 2019) try option `--no-progress-meter`.

According to [man page](https://curl.se/docs/manpage.html):

> --no-progress-meter
>
> Option to switch off the progress meter output without muting or otherwise affecting warning and informational messages like --silent does.
>
> Note that this is the negated option name documented. You can thus use --progress-meter to enable the progress meter again.
>
> Example:
>
> curl --no-progress-meter -o store https://example.com
>
> See also -v, --verbose and -s, --silent. Added in 7.67.0.